Postgresql: Modify a value in nested json
I am looking for psql query to update the jsonb property value inside jsonb column in my_table. my_table is something like below where 'details' is jsonb:
production_id | uuid
deleted | boolean
details | jsonb

Sample data for details is:
{
    "id": "V_12345",
    "cars": [
        {
            "id": "b_1111",
            "type": "SportsCar",
            "lauches": [
                {
                    "id": "S_2112",
                    "year": 2024,                        
                    "nextUpdate": "2024"              
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "c_222",
            "type": "PickupTruck",
            "lauches": [
                {
                    "id": "P_2113",
                    "year": 2024,                        
                    "nextUpdate": "2025"              
                }
            ]
        }
    ]    
}

How to update the value of details-->cars[i]-->launches-->'nextUpdate' for the following match: where details-->id='V_12345' and cars-->id='b_1111' and cars-->'type'='SportsCar'

This can be done with the help of jsonb_set, jsonb_agg and jsonb_build_object :
UPDATE my_table
SET details = jsonb_set(details, '{cars}', s.cars)
FROM (
    SELECT jsonb_agg(                                               
                 jsonb_build_object(                                            
                    'id', cars ->> 'id',
                    'type', cars ->> 'type',
                    'lauches', CASE WHEN cars ->> 'type' = 'SportsCar' THEN 
                                  jsonb_set(cars -> 'lauches', '{0,nextUpdate}', '"NEW_VALUE"')
                               ELSE cars -> 'lauches' END
        )
      ) as cars
    FROM my_table
    CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(details->'cars') as cars
    WHERE details->>'id' = 'V_12345' 
) s;


jsonb_array_elements() expands the array cars into one row per element.

jsonb_set() replace the value of each element. when the condition is validated

jsonb_agg() reaggregates the elements into a new array.


Demo here
